# How to Create RecyclerView without causing app to freeze

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-asynctask

Before Starting Off,I must tell that I am an Absolute Beginner in Android Development, so I need help in not only solving the problem but I also need an insight on how things are actually working.

So I am building an app which provides me Live Updates of Covid-19 Cases in my country(India) and the World. My app has 1 Main Activity and 2 Fragments.

[Fragment 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVYUV.jpg)

[Fragment 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSoMt.jpg)

Both these Fragments contain a RecyclerView. The RecyclerView in Fragment 1 is relatively smaller(contains about 35 elements) but the RecyclerView in Fragment 2 contains a list of about 200 countries.

As I start my app, I want both these RecyclerViews to be loaded.

The task is simple : Call the API->Parse the JSON->Update the Adapter-> Set the Adapter to the RecyclerView.

Problem : The app UI freezes(for about 10 seconds) as I start the app.

I searched in Stack Overflow and in Youtube and what I did until now is to Create a MyASyncTask which calls the API(for Fragment 2) in background and updates the RecyclerView.

```
class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Example_Item, Void> {

private ArrayList<Example_Item> ExampleList;//Represents the list of data of the Recycler View
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private ExampleAdapter mAdapter;
private Context mContext;
private View RootView;
private String URL;



public MyAsyncTask(Context context, View v,RecyclerView rv,String url,ArrayList<Example_Item> arrayList) {
    mContext = context;
    RootView=v;
    mRecyclerView =rv;
    URL=url;
    ExampleList=arrayList;

}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    mAdapter=new ExampleAdapter(ExampleList);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Example_Item... values) {
    ExampleList.add(values[0]);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    HttpsTrustManager.allowAllSSL();
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);

    JsonArrayRequest arrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            URL,
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d("Covid", "SUCCESS! JSON: " + response.toString());
                    CovidData_Countries covidData = CovidData_Countries.fromJSON(response);
                    if(covidData!=null) {
                        int len = covidData.arr.length;
                        for (int i = 0; i < len ; i++) {
                            publishProgress(covidData.arr[i]);
                        }


                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("Covid", "Fail " + error.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(RootView.getContext(), "Request Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
    );
    requestQueue.add(arrayRequest);
    return null;
}
```

***Some Side Notes of the above Code:***

Example_Item is a class which represents each list Item of the RecyclerView.
CovidData_Countries is a class which parses the JSON. It has a public data member arr[](of type Example_Item) which stores all objects of Items that goes into the RecyclerView.

***What I want my app to work Like :***
As I open my App, The Fragment 1 RecyclerView will immediately load up(which actually does, it takes about 0.5 seconds) and I want the RecyclerView in Fragment 2 to load up gradually(without causing app UI to freeze up). By gradually I mean Item-By-Item if it is difficult to load all at once.

I thought after adding the MyAsyncTask class, the app UI won't freeze up, but it does freeze.

It might happen that my MyAsyncTask is completely wrong. In that case, it will be really helpful if you could show me the correct way to implement it in background.

My Adapter Code:

```
package com.app.learning.covid_19;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ExampleAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleAdapter.ExampleViewHolder> 
{
private ArrayList<Example_Item> mExample_items;

public static class ExampleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView mState;//Represents States of India(for Fragment 1) or Country Name(Fragment 2)
    public TextView mConfirmed;//Total Confirmed Cases
    public TextView mRecovered;//Total Recovered Cases
    public TextView mDeceased;//Total Deaths
    public TextView mdConfirmed;//Delta Confirmed Cases(New Cases)
    public TextView mdRecovered;//Delta Recovered Cases(New Recoveries)
    public TextView mdDeceased;//Delta Deaths Cases(New Deaths)

    public ExampleViewHolder(View itemView)
    {
        super(itemView);
        mState=itemView.findViewById(R.id.state);
        mConfirmed=itemView.findViewById(R.id.confirm);
        mRecovered=itemView.findViewById(R.id.recover);
        mDeceased=itemView.findViewById(R.id.decease);
        mdConfirmed=itemView.findViewById(R.id.dconfirm);
        mdRecovered=itemView.findViewById(R.id.drecover);
        mdDeceased=itemView.findViewById(R.id.ddecease);
    }

}
public ExampleAdapter(ArrayList<Example_Item> RowList){
    mExample_items=RowList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ExampleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row,parent,false);
    ExampleViewHolder evh=new ExampleViewHolder(v);
    return evh;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ExampleViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Example_Item currenItem=mExample_items.get(position);
    holder.mState.setText(currenItem.getState());
    holder.mConfirmed.setText(currenItem.getConf());
    holder.mRecovered.setText(currenItem.getRec());
    holder.mDeceased.setText(currenItem.getDec());
    holder.mdConfirmed.setText(currenItem.getDconf());
    holder.mdRecovered.setText(currenItem.getDrec());
    holder.mdDeceased.setText(currenItem.getDdec());
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mExample_items.size();
}
```

}

Comment: Can you provide code of recyclerView where you are adding data to view..

Comment: Also, avoid AsyncTask for background task and use RxJava or Kotlin Coroutines. You can find plenty of tutorials on making an API call using these.

Comment: dazziete, Can you please provide what are the drawbacks of using a ASyncTask?The problem that I have stated, is it because of ASyncTask or there is some error at my end?

Comment: The implementation of your async task doesn't look _wrong_, but it doesn't look perfect either. I would expect the slow parts of the task to be (1) fetching the json data from the network and (2) parsing the json into your object type. But you are using `publishProgress()` just to fill up the list one by one, and I don't think that's any better than updating the list all at once.

Comment: Your `onProgressUpdate()` method is adding a single item to the list, but then calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`. This causes the entire RecyclerView to refresh, but since you're just inserting a single item, you only need to refresh that one position in the recycler. Try using `mAdatper.notifyItemInserted(...)` instead.

Comment: Even despite my above comments, I suspect that the real problem is in the `RecyclerView` tag in your layout file. If the app is hanging for multiple seconds, that makes it sound like it is creating and binding more `ViewHolder`s at once than it should. Does your `RecyclerView` tag use `wrap_content` for its height? That is generally not a good idea.

Comment: @BenP. So I have changed mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() to mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(int position) but it hasn't solved the problem. Also My RecyclerView has "match parent" for both layout height and layout width which itself is inside a NestedScrollView.I would also like to mention the api freezes(for about 10 seconds) on real smartphones(tested in 2 devices) but it hardly freezes(for about 1 sec) in emulator.